# Error de lectura XML: mal formado IIS

Tags: c#, webservice, visual-studio-2017, iis, .asmx

soy nuevo en el manejo de **web services** he terminado mi clase producto y mi webservice.asmx más adelante muestro el código, bueno el caso es que cuando publico de manera correcta el web service en IIS no hay errores todo bien, mucho antes de volverla aplicación, en el panel Administrador del IIS agregue las extenciones .asmx en los MIME, luego pase a convertir la carpeta de la web service en aplicación, active el examen de directorios y luego le di en examinar y el resultado siguiente es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se cual sea le error pero igual dejo el código  **Clase Productos**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebDrinks
{
    public class Productos
    {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_categoria { get; set; }
    public int id_subcategoria { get; set; }
    public String titulo { get; set; }
    public String titular { get; set; }
    public String descripcion { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public decimal precio { get; set; }
    public String imagen { get; set; }

    public Productos()
    {
        this.id = 0;
        this.id_categoria = 0;
        this.id_subcategoria = 0;
        this.titulo = "";
        this.titular = "";
        this.descripcion = "";
        this.stock = 0;
        this.precio = 0;
        this.imagen = "";
    }

    public Productos(int id, int cat, int subc, String ti, String titu, String des, int stock, decimal precio, String img)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.id_categoria = cat;
        this.id_subcategoria = subc;
        this.titulo = ti;
        this.titular = titu;
        this.descripcion = des;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.imagen = img;
        }
    }
}
```

**WebService**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace WebDrinks
 {
    /// <summary>
   /// Descripción breve de WebDrinks
   /// </summary>
   [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
   [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
   [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // Para permitir que se llame a este servicio web desde un script, usando ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente. 
   // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebDrinks : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
            (@"data source=DESKTOP-9695OA0\MSSQLSERVER1; initial catalog=drinks2u;user id=sa;password=sahc");

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hola a todos";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public Productos[] listarProductos()
    {
        Productos[] lista = null;
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Productos";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<Productos> list = new List<Productos>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            list.Add(new Productos(dr.GetInt32(0), dr.GetInt32(1), dr.GetInt32(2), dr.GetString(3), dr.GetString(4), dr.GetString(5),
                dr.GetInt32(6), dr.GetDecimal(7), dr.GetString(8)));
         }

        lista = list.ToArray();
        con.Close();
        return lista;
        }

    [WebMethod]
    public void InsertarUsuario(String nom, String correo, String pass, Char dir, String img)
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (@nom,@correo,@pass,@dir,@img)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nom", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = nom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@correo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = correo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pass;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = dir;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = img;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
       }
    }
}
```

Aquí lo que agregue al IIS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por que has añadido `asmx` a los tipos mime? no es necesario. Por otro lado..que esperas ver al acceder al webservice desde el navegador? el webservice debes consumirlo desde una aplicacion.

Comment: Hola, sitúate en el explorador de soluciones en tu archivo asmx. botón derecho y  `View markup` (verás que se abre el editor de XML) Revisa dicho contenido XML

Comment: Hola @Pikoh debo de ver un resultado de mis datos donde hago mi consulta de mi bd, hola Sergio ya abrí lo que me comentas me aparece exactamente lo mismo, bueno esto me aparece:
    <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebDrinks.asmx.cs" Class="WebDrinks.WebDrinks" %>

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra me aparece esto cuando abro lo que me dijiste:
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebDrinks.asmx.cs" Class="WebDrinks.WebDrinks" %> 
¿Que debo hacer ?

Comment: Hola he visto que cuando publico el web service en IIS no funciona y me muestra esos errores, pero cuando desde el VS2017 incio la aplicacion con despuracion me funciona correctamente, ¿Aque se de debe ?

Comment: Otra pregunta.... Has configurado correctamente asp. Net? La caracteristica está en. Abre Panel Control de Windows, Haz clic en “Programas” y luego selecciona “Activar o desactivar las características de Windows” en Programas y características. Mira que tengas activadas las de asp. Net

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra si lo tengo habilitado tanto la version 4.5 como 2.5